# How do I connect remotely to SQL Server from Windows client?

Tags: mac-osx, windows-xp, sql-server-2005, database, remote

Having a bit of an issue connecting to SQL SERVER remotely from Windows.  I've verified that all of my settings are correct via SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO EXPRESS and SQL SERVER CONFIGURATION MANAGER.

I can connect remotely using ODBC drivers from other OSes (e.g. OS X, Linux, etc).  However, when I connect with the same credentials from a remote Windows machine using "SQL SERVER" as the driver I am told that the system cannot connect.

I've tried creating an ODBC Data Source and I get the same error:

```
Connection failed:
SQLState: '01000'
SQL Server Error: 14
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets]ConnectionOpen(InvalidInstance()).
Connection failed:
SQLState: '08001'
SQL Server Error: 14
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets]Invalid Connection
```

From the non-windows machines I can use the IP address of the SQL Server just fine.  However, on the remote Windows machine, neither IP address nor named instance works.  FYI, I *can* create an ODBC Data Source using the named instance on the machine actually running the SQL Server (but this is, of course, nothing special -- just proof that it isn't completely hosed).

One interesting note:  If I use SQL STUDIO 2005 from a Windows client machine, I can use the IP address to connect remotely.  Still, the whole reason I bring this up is because I need to use a software package I've written to connect to SQL Server remotely from Windows machines as well.  Previously the solution was only needed to xfer data from SQL Server into a PostGRES or MySQL database on non-Windows machines (due to DBA preference).  However, now they also want to move the data from the legacy software to MySQL even on Windows.

Any assistance would be most appreciated.  Feel free to provide a full example connection string.

Best

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like its trying to connect and look for the instance name of the SQL server in being very specific.

Looking at the log with the ODBC Data source it is mentioning that its an InvalidInstance most likely referencing the name, is it still set to the default name?

If it is default the name might be along these lines for the ODBC connection
\computer_name\MSSQLSERVER